# How to access a variable of a instrumented method using a javaagent?

Tags: java, jdbc, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I have been trying to obtain values from instrumented method. Using $1, $0 to obtain parameter values and current object variables has worked fine. But now I would like to take a value from a object used in the method.

For an example suppose I am instrumenting [org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.4.187/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcPreparedStatement.java#JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery%28%29) class. I want obtain the connection url by using the conn variable used in line 112 in the method body. (JdbcConnection class contain url as a attribute) But when I use as,

```
conn.getURL()
```

it throws `CannotCompileException` saying there is no class named conn.

How can I obtain that URL? Is it something possible with javassist or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javassist Tutorial](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#before), `$0` refers to `this` (`$1` onwards are the parameters), so you could use

```
$0.conn.getURL()
```

or

```
$0.getConnection().getURL()
```

to access the connection.